# Mongoose .dot Notation equivalent for $and + $in + $or?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am looking to `'.find'` all docs, `'.where'` the username is `'.in'` the to: array and either upVoted: true `'.or'` noVote: true, all sorted by rank descending

Here's an example doc structure:

```
to: [String],
voting: {
  upVoted: Boolean,
  noVote: Boolean,
  downVoted: Boolean
},
rank: Number
```

This query is working, but how would this be written in [Mongoose .dot notation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html):

```
Story.find({
    $and: [
          { to: { $in: [ 'user1' ] } },
        { $or: [{ 'voting.upVote': true }, { 'voting.noVote': true }] }
    ]
}, function (err, stories) {
```

FYI am working on the correct syntax for sorting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query can be made simpler, because you don't need $and (it's implicit in MongoDB). Also, if you are looking for only one user from the `ṫo` array, then you also don't need the $in operator.

```
{
    to: 'user1',
    $or: [{ 'voting.upVote': true }, { 'voting.noVote': true }] 
}
```

Using Mongoose query API:

```
var query = Story.find();
query.where('to', 'user1');
query.or({ 'voting.upVote': true }, { 'voting.noVote': true });
query.exec(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) ...
});
```

Or if you're looking for more than one user then replace:

```
query.where('to', 'user1');
```

with:

```
query.where('to').in(['user1', 'user2']);
```

Comment: thanks for this.. any reason why the results are only returning for upVote: true, without including noVote: true ?

Comment: also, would agregrate be necessary for sorting by `sort([['rank','descending']])` ?

Comment: appreciate the dot notation answer.. am now using .aggregate though, for sorting..

Comment: @StackThis you can sort your results even without aggregation using ˙sort` method.